# Wordpress menu cannot be centered

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working with the site cardinalmma.com/ but you can see that the menu is not centered. For example see the news menu its in the left portion but with some padding. I want it to be centered can anyone help me.
thanks
Somdeb

Comment: Vertically or horizontally centered?

Comment: at least try to find your self.if then any issue occur then post your effort here.this question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the individual navbar labels centered, correct?

```
li.menu-item {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This targets the `<li>` tags in your menu, identified by the `.menu-item` class. The `text-align: center;` rule takes care of centering the `<a>` tag with your text in it.

In my browser, this modification makes it look like this:

[image: menu with centered text]

Answer (score 1):

Try something in your css stylesheet to make the menu items be align center.

try something with the class menu and the li part:

```
.menu {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or something in that direction

Answer (score 0):

Please update your css. This should resolve your issue.

```
.menu_top a {
color: #eee;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 3.4em;
padding: 0 14px;
text-decoration: none;
height: 50px !important;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

.menu_top ul ul li a {
 text-align:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the navbar labels use this css courtesy of Surreal Dreams:

```
li.menu-item {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now to elaborate on how to find this solution. The best way to edit/develop CSS for wordpress is to use firebug or Chrome's developer tools to find the element you want to modify.Then you can add CSS right there and see the results real-time (these changes are not permanent). I would say it is likely this is how Surreal Dreams found the solution.

- If you want to learn more about using the Chrome dev tools tool go to this page: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/.
- If you are new to CSS (I dont know if you are new to CSS or if youre problem is strictly editing CSS) for wordpress you should go check out http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web